# Get item from array based on hashed string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, type-conversion, digest

I would like to extract an element from an array, predictably based on a string input.

My use case: Generate a color for a user, based on name.

One (faulty) implementation would be to generate a hash from the user name, and reduce it to a value between 0-25 like so:

```
def color
  colors = array_of_25_colors
  colors[Digest::MD5.hexdigest(name).to_i(16) & 25]
end
```

This implementation only returns 8 possible colors, so no good.

**EDIT**

Another implementation I've tried is to use the byte code from the first character in the name, but since I allow unicode in names this is not practical:

```
"aaron".first.bytes.first - 97
=> 0 #Okay!
"zac".first.bytes.first - 97
=> 25 #Nice!
"örjan".first.bytes.first - 97
=> 98 #Doh!
```

What could a working implementation look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add up the ordinal values of each character in the string then divide mod 25 like this:

```
colors = array_of_25_colors
colors[name.bytes.reduce(:+) % 25]
```

Comment: Ive been using "&" thinking that was the divmod operator like a sucker!! Thanks. :)

Comment: using `bytes` like @theTRON suggests below makes this a little cleaner: `colors[name.bytes.reduce(:+) % 25]`

Answer (score 2):

Building on your use of `#bytes`, you could also go with something like:

```
colors[name.bytes.inject(:+) % 25]
```

Comment: Thanks! Just curious, why .inject(:+) instead of .sum?

Comment: @RichardJohansson `Array` does not have a built-in sum method last time I checked. It appears Rails does, though ([documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum))

Comment: Ah, thanks. Not easy knowing what framework adds what methods sometimes when they feel like natural Ruby…